Image (Error) User memory limit exceeded in Google Earth Engine
I wrote a code that can estimate the rainfall for each day of the year in a given range and then find the maximum daily rainfall for each pixel of my image. I encountered an error (Image (Error) User memory limit exceeded).
This is not the end of the story because I need to find the maximum daily rainfall for each pixel for ten years.
If it is impossible from Google Earth Engine, how can I do it?
Below you can see my code.
Map.centerObject(table);

// Load GPM dataset
var gpm = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V07")
  .filterBounds(table) // Filter bar asase marz (table)
  .select('precipitation') // Entekhab bande shadate baresh
  .filterDate('2007-01-01', '2007-01-30') // Filter tarikhi baraye yek sal
  .map(function(img) {
    return img.clip(table); // Clip bar asase marz
  });

// Convert precipitation intensity to half-hour rainfall
var calculateHalfHourRainfall = function(image) {
  return image.divide(2).rename('half_hour_rainfall') // Tabdil be baresh nimsaate
             .set('date', image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')); // Set tarikh dar metadata
};

var halfHourRainfall = gpm.map(calculateHalfHourRainfall); // Ejra-ye tabee bar tamami tasavir

// Extract unique dates and calculate daily rainfall
var uniqueDates = halfHourRainfall.aggregate_array('date').distinct(); // Estekhraj tarikhhaye monhaser be fard

var dailyRainfall = uniqueDates.map(function(date) {
  date = ee.String(date); // Tabdil be string
  var dailyImages = halfHourRainfall.filter(ee.Filter.eq('date', date)); // Filter tasavir baraye in tarikh
  var dailySum = dailyImages.sum().rename('daily_rainfall'); // Jam'e tasavir baraye in rooz
  return dailySum.set('date', date); // Set tarikh dar metadata tasvir rooz
});

// Convert to ImageCollection for further processing
dailyRainfall = ee.ImageCollection(dailyRainfall);

// Calculate maximum daily rainfall for the year
var maxDailyRainfall = dailyRainfall.max(); // Peyda kardane maaksimum baraye har pixel

 Visualize the result
Map.addLayer(maxDailyRainfall, 
{min: 0, max: 100, palette: ['blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']}, 'Maximum Daily Rainfall');

 Print results
print('Daily Rainfall Collection:', dailyRainfall);
print('Maximum Daily Rainfall:', maxDailyRainfall);


Your script runs for me, without memory error.
To get a maximum daily rainfall during a 10 year period, you could perhaps do something like the below. It's slow, but rendered without error.
var startYear = 2007
var endYear = 2017

var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear, 1, 1)
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endYear + 1, 1, 1)
var numberOfDays = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days')

var gpm = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V07")
  .select('precipitation')
var daily = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays.subtract(1))
    .map(function (dayOffset) {
      var date = startDate.advance(dayOffset, 'days')
      return gpm
        .filterDate(date.getRange('day'))
        .mean() // Mean mm/hr
        .multiply(24) // mm for 24h
        .set('system:time_start', date.millis())
    })
)
var maxDaily = daily.reduce(ee.Reducer.max())

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5e2d7fc8d3a0a052c83839f18ed81e7a
